# Install pillow OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install Pillow on mavericks with no luck.

I have tried:

```
pip install Pillow
```

The install works great.

However I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named PIL

On this line of code in my script:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
```

I have no idea whats wrong.  Ideas?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed? Likely what is happening is you are installing `Pillow` with one version (say, the system Python) and trying to import it with another version (from python.org, Homebrew, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

@MattDMo was right.

I had done `brew install python` to install python with homebrew leaving with system python and homebrew python.

I removed that brew and did an `easy_install pip`, then `pip install Pillow`.

Everything is working great now

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```
import Image
```

In some installs, `Import PIL`works, in some others `import Image`is the one that works.

It is quite confusing.

Comment: This is not true. `import PIL` and/or `from PIL import ...` work just fine with Pillow on Linux, OS X, and Windows.